# Find out when underage Facebook users interact with my age-restricted app?

Tags: facebook, api

Here's a hard one I can't figure out.

Facebook lets me define age restrictions for my apps. But my app uses the chat API, and I have no idea how old most nonusers are. So I can't stop my users from sending messages to their friends who are under 18 - and because of the age restriction on my app, instead of those chat messages, their underage friends see this!: https://trello-attachments.s3.amazonaws.com/51f5ced593a7fe587d002132/522a88190e18c7f824005e8a/2fddd994ac56fbf687060ea2beb89c4c/upload_2013-09-06_at_6.57.47_pm.png

This is certainly not what I want, and it makes everybody look bad, including my users.

Is there a way to get any sort of feedback when an underage user engages with the app (for example, views an invite from a friend), so I can prevent them from receiving messages entirely?

Or is there a way to determine or estimate age for people on Facebook who have not used my app?

Or is there a different way to solve this problem? I can't figure it out.

Thank you.